# Helm + K8S - access the persistent volume

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes

I am using *K8S* with *Helm 3*.

I am also using *MYSQL 5.7* database.

I created *MYSQL* pod, whenever the database persists (it is created after first time the pod is created, and even the pod is down and up again, the data won't be lost).

I am using `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim`.

Here are the *YAML* files:

**Mysql pod:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myproject-db
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    name: myproject-db
    app: myproject-db
spec:
  hostname: myproject-db
  subdomain: {{ include "k8s.db.subdomain" . }}
  containers:
    - name: myproject-db
      image: mysql:5.7
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      env:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      ports:
        - name: mysql
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 3306
      resources: 
        requests: 
          cpu: 200m
          memory: 500Mi
        limits:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 600Mi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistence-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumes:
    - name: mysql-persistence-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mysql-pvc
```

**Persistent Volume:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
    name: mysql-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/mysql"
```

**Persistent Volume Claim:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: mysql-pv
```

after running:

Helm install myproject myproject/

The database is created, and can be used.

If I add records and stop and remove the database pod - there is no loss of db records, even
I restart the pod by running: `helm delete myproject`
and by running: `helm install myproject myproject/` again.

I see that the db data is kept when the MYSQL pod is restarted.

How can I access the data of mysql?

I see no files on /var/lib/mysql  neither on /data/mysql - how can I access those two paths?

Also - how can I delete permanently the data? (can I delete the files themselves or just by kubectl commands?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hostPath volume, thus the persistence is directly on your node.
You can ssh to your node and delete those files.

Comment: When I do: ls /data/mysql or ls /var/lib/mysql I see no files (/var/lib/mysql is in the pod, but where is the /data/mysql folder contents?